# GLM fails to build when using Clion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, glfw, glm-math

I am using the experimental GLM hash features in a CMake project.
Everything works fine unless the project is generated by Clion.

When building the Clion generated project GLM raises the error "GLM_GTX_hash requires C++11 standard library support" (see CMake logs) although C++11 is enabled.
Building the same, clion generated, project from a terminal fails with the same error.

However, when generating and building the project with cmake 'manually' (without Clion even knowing about it) everything works fine. As expected.

GLM is not directly included in the CMakeList. GLFW includes/imports it.

Example CMakeLists.txt

```
(...)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(Test main.cpp)
(...)
add_subdirectory("glfw" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/glfw)
target_include_directories(Test PUBLIC ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(Test ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} glfw)
```

Example main.cpp

```cpp
#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL
#include <glm/gtx/hash.hpp>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Clion build output:

```
/usr/bin/cmake --build /home/lukas/Test/cmake-build-debug --target Test -- -j 2
[ 89%] Built target glfw
Scanning dependencies of target Test
[ 94%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /home/lukas/Test/main.cpp:8:
/usr/include/glm/gtx/hash.hpp:46:3: error: "GLM_GTX_hash requires C++11 standard library support"
#       error "GLM_GTX_hash requires C++11 standard library support"
        ^
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: Test] Error 2
```

Terminal output (as expected)

```
$ cmake -H. -Bbuild -G "Unix Makefiles" && cmake --build build                                                                                                                 
Scanning dependencies of target glfw
[  5%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/init.c.o
[ 15%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/input.c.o
[ 21%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/monitor.c.o
[ 26%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/vulkan.c.o
[ 31%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.o
[ 36%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_init.c.o
[ 42%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_monitor.c.o
[ 47%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/x11_window.c.o
[ 52%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/xkb_unicode.c.o
[ 57%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/posix_time.c.o
[ 63%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/posix_thread.c.o
[ 68%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/glx_context.c.o
[ 73%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/egl_context.c.o
[ 78%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/osmesa_context.c.o
[ 84%] Building C object glfw/src/CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/linux_joystick.c.o
[ 89%] Linking C static library libglfw3.a
[ 89%] Built target glfw
Scanning dependencies of target Test
[ 94%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable Test
[100%] Built target Test
```

Now I am actually curious about rather I messed up somewhere or if it is simply a bug. And if so, where should I report it?
[Clion/Jetbrains?, GLM?, GLFW?, CMake?]

Thanks in advance

## Update

I am using the latest available (for me) builds:
CMake version: 3.14.4
Operating System: Arch Linux 5.0.18-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
GLFW version/commit: d834f01c
GLM version/commit: fce2abd0
Clion: 2019.1.3
Clion EAP: 2019.2 EAP

## Final update / 'Solution'

I just discovered that the problem is Clang, not Clion or anything else.
Clion simply defaulted to Clang (instead of GCC).
There are bug reports for GLM and Clang already existing (with potential fixes!):

- https://github.com/g-truc/glm/issues/620
- https://github.com/g-truc/glm/issues/646

Thank you very much everyone ~

Comment: What operating system are you on? What compiler and version are you using? What cmake version are you using? Build problems are highly dependent on these variables, so it is important to include them in questions like this.

Comment: Damn ... totally forgot about that. Thank you very much! 
Will update.

Comment: I, too, am running Arch Linux and I have Clion. I, however, have GLM installed via pacman. I am able to compile your example main.cpp in Clion just fine. As such, I suspect that the issue is that you are including the GLM version in GLFW, which may be out-dated. Furthermore, you are including GLFW via some sort of git submodule type thing. This isn't a good idea. (1/3)

Comment: On Linux, it is ideal to install a package by the package manager and then use one of 3 systems to link to it within cmake (plain target_link_libraries works fine if you just want Linux support, pkg-config, or find_package). Then, all but one of those works fine on Windows if you build the library, designate a directory to install it to, and then tell CMake about that directory. (2/3)

Comment: Sometimes, you'll need to copy some DLLs that you compiled with the libraries into the directory of the executable. You can also try static linking, but that is usually more trouble than it's worth as most libraries are written with the assumption of dynamic linking. (3/3)

Comment: @john01dav to have better cross-platform support I wanted to build most, if not all, libraries from source. That is why I am not using the AUR/Pacman library.
Though, even if I remove the GLM submodule GLFW gets GLM from somewhere (guessing it is the locally installed package) and everything still is the same. Works in CLI and literally everywhere else, but not in Clion.
I also tried to let CMake include GLM with pkg-config and find_package, same results.

Comment: You can have cross platform support with separately loaded packages. In fact, that is ideal because each package then gets its own cmake project to build itself, thus reducing the chance of them stepping on each-others toes (I have had this issue happen before where I built two large libraries in the same cmake project and they kept trying to overwrite each other's global settings). If you have a cmake project that works without Clion but does not work with Clion, however, that sounds like something to report to Jetbrains.

Comment: Can anyone confirm this -supposedly- bug though? Maybe my toolchain is just broken or something else is wrong ...
I would setup a gitlab repository with the exact setup which fails on my machine if anyone wanna try?

Comment: If your program works outside of Clion, then your toolchain is not the issue. You should definitely give Jetbrains that git repository.

Comment: Alright, thanks for helping out!